# jQuery find() in an HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML string:

```
let str = '<div><p>text1</p><p>text2</p></div>'
```

I'm interested in using jQuery's `find()` to identify elements within the string. Yet, when I try:

```
str.find('div p')
```

I get this error:

```
 TypeError: str.find is not a function
```

Is there any conversion I must do to `str`? What should I do?

Comment: Why do you use `this`? If you pass it to `myFunction(str)` then inside you'd just use it as `str`.

Comment: Could you post a copy of your entire function and how you're calling it? My suspicion is the same as @VLAZ, I'm pretty sure you don't need `this`.

Comment: @karim doesn't matter where it is - when you have a function that takes a parameter, you never use `this` to access the parameter. `this` refers to the *context* of the function and it's not at all relevant for the parameters.

Comment: @karim Hmmm, that's interesting... I'm afraid we can't help you though without seeing the entire function, including how its declared, and its context..?

Comment: Then what is your aim here? Strings don't have a `find` method. Are you trying to find text in it or do you want to treat it as HTML and find elements? Do you expect HTMLElement/HTMLCollection out of it or a jQuery wrapper around those?

Comment: What do you think you’ll “find”, even if that was a string method? Are you confusing a string with a dom representation if the string was converted to dom elements?

Comment: `find()` is for arrays. You want something like `indexOf()`

Comment: Before you use the `find` method, you string needs to be html context first, in which I would suggest you take a look at [DOMParser](https://alligator.io/js/domparser/) or [.parseHtml](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) in jquery

Comment: That’s one way, since you’re using jQuery.

Comment: You could convert the string to a DOM element using jQuery: `$.parseHTML(str)`. I might be wrong, but you could probably do that in a single line, like `$.parseHTML(str).find("div")`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$(str).find()` because it's still a string which doesn't have a find method. `jQuery object` has a  `find` method which you can use to search in the DOM object you gave.